# when running expo build:ios, getting invalid credentials even though I can sign in manually

Tags: ios, expo, apple-developer

I am developing an app to run on web and ios, using Expo (with rnw for the web component). I decided to begin to set up the app store presence today -- but I am running into issues:

```
We need your Apple ID/password to ensure the correct teamID and appID

Note: Expo does not keep your Apple ID or your Apple password.

? What's your Apple ID? MY_VALID_APPLE_ID
? Password? [hidden]
[16:22:23] Validating Credentials...
[16:22:24] Error while gathering & validating credentials
[16:22:24] Reason:Invalid credentials, raw:"Invalid username and password combination. Used 'MY_VALID_APPLE_ID' as the username."
[16:22:24] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I can log in just fine with these same credentials using the web. I thought to try to turn off 2FA, but apple doesn't allow that any longer.

It would be great if someone could verify that apple hasn't implemented a change for 2FA that broke expo -- I know expo started working with Apple's 2FA about a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post an answer to this.

I can verify with certainty that it was not accepting my password containing a space, and that when I changed my appleID password, it began working. I submitted a issue with expo team and two people checked and said they had no such issue with a matching build environment. Apple never posted any outage details.

there was likely a small network problem that day where I lived that quickly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try running expo:build ios  with powershell. It did the trick for me.